# Jquery call back not firing in bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to get my callback to fire unless I paste the code into the console. If I do that, it works. Seems to be some kind of scoping issue or something because of the dynamic nature of the bootstrap tabs.

HTML

```
<input type="file" class="fileElem pull-right" id="logoUpload" multiple onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
<ul id="files"></ul>
<span class="fileSelect pull-right" id="logoSelectUpload"> Choose File</span>
```

JQ

```
//turn the bootstrap tab on so elements are ready

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            function click(el) {
                    // Simulate click on the element.
                    var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
                    evt.initEvent('click', true, true);
                    el.dispatchEvent(evt);
            }
            document.querySelector('#logoSelectUpload').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    var fileInput = document.querySelector('#logoUpload');
                    //click(fileInput); // Simulate the click with a custom event.
                    fileInput.click(); // Or, use the native click() of the file input.
            }, false);

            //callback will only work if I paste it into the console

            function handleFiles(files) {
                    //call backs
                    var list = [].slice.call(files).map(function(file) {
                            return '<li>' + file.name + '</li>';
                    }).join('');

                    document.getElementById('files').innerHTML = list;
            }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback function is scoped inside the event handler. Try:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            function click(el) {
                    // Simulate click on the element.
                    var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
                    evt.initEvent('click', true, true);
                    el.dispatchEvent(evt);
            }
            document.querySelector('#logoSelectUpload').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    var fileInput = document.querySelector('#logoUpload');
                    //click(fileInput); // Simulate the click with a custom event.
                    fileInput.click(); // Or, use the native click() of the file input.
            }, false);

            //callback will only work if I paste it into the console

});

function handleFiles(files) {
     //call backs
     var list = [].slice.call(files).map(function(file) {
           return '<li>' + file.name + '</li>';
      }).join('');

      document.getElementById('files').innerHTML = list;
}
```